# how shall I get the best weight allocation vector?

Tags: algorithms

Know values: matrix—— X,F,and u;

wanted value: vector—— w;

restrictive condition：

$$R=\sum_{j=1}^n w_j *\sum_{k=1}^k (x_{jk}*f_{jk}+u_j); $$
$$P=\sqrt{w^T*(XFX^T+Delta)w}$$

Now shall I set vector — ‘w’ to get the biggest value of R/P?

Comment: You might have more luck if you write out the condition, especially if you take the time to learn a little bit about how to format mathematics on this website.

Comment: thanks for your advice; I have done it.